# Keeping Objects persistent in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr, shared-memory

Below is my code for an attempt to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ObjectHoldingData {
public:
    ObjectHoldingData(int item);
    int item;
};

ObjectHoldingData::ObjectHoldingData (int item) {
    this->item = item;
}

vector<ObjectHoldingData*> listOfObjectsWithData;

class ObjectGenerator {
public: 
    ObjectGenerator(int counter);
    void run();
    int counter;
};

ObjectGenerator::ObjectGenerator (int counter) {
    this->counter = counter;
}

void ObjectGenerator::run () {
    ObjectHoldingData *obj = new ObjectHoldingData(counter);

    listOfObjectsWithData.push_back(obj);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listOfObjectsWithData.size(); ++i) {
        ObjectHoldingData *currObj = listOfObjectsWithData.at(i);
        cout << "Object " << currObj->item << " with memory reference " << &currObj << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ObjectGenerator *generator = new ObjectGenerator(i);
        generator->run();
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 10; i < 20; ++i) {
        ObjectGenerator *generator = new ObjectGenerator(i);
        generator->run();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is how can all the objects within the listOfObjectsWithData has the same memory reference (when printed out with &).

Also, I wasn't able to successfully reproduce what I wanted to convey. For the problem I have, I am trying to store AST nodes in a list like my example above. But when trying to access it, it gets segmentation fault in no time at all during the second run-time instance (trying to simulate the multiple run-time instance using 2 for-loops in the main method, not sure if this is appropriate)

My guess is that the different run-time instance makes it such that the previous run-time pointer value may have been overriden by something else altogether.

But if that is the case, why does the example above not run into segmentation fault? Is it because of the 'new' keyword operator?

Comment: To produce a [mcve], reduce rather than rewrite, keep intermediate versions, and test that the problem occurs as you reduce so you do not overshoot.  If a given reduction removes the problem, vary the reduction rather than give up (assuming you did not figure out what went wrong from the reduction that solved the problem).  [Mcve] via reproducton often fails, because if you understood what matters, you wouldn't usually need help understanding what you did wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite get it. What do you mean reduce rather than rewrite? This is my first time trying to give an example like this, only pity is I didn't manage to reproduce to error though.

Comment: @JeremyKuah a minimal example is useless if it does not reproduce the error. Try again.

Answer (score 4):

> What I don't understand is how can all the objects within the listOfObjectsWithData has the same memory reference (when printed out with &).

You print the memory address of the local pointer variable `currObj`. A local variable will be in the same location on every iteration of the loop.

> why does the example above not run into segmentation fault?

There is no reason for the above program to have a segfault. There are no illegal memory accesses. The behaviour of the program is well defined, although you do leak all the allocated memory.

Comment: Hmm, is that because the object `ObjectHoldingData` is created with a `new` keyword?

In my original problem.. I'm only given pointers and I try to add that into a `std::map`. And by the time I reach the 2nd run-time instance of the program, whenever I try to access the elements stored in the `std::map` from the 1st run-time instance it won't work. And it ends up in `segmentation fault`. 

Am I right to say that this is because the memory has been `deleted` or `deallocated` already? And if I store it as a `new` object, this would not happen.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by leak all the allocated memory?

Comment: By leak, I mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Yes, the memory is leaked because it was allocated with `new`, but not deleted. It is impossible to say why segmentation fault happens with a program that I haven't seen.

Answer (score 3):

`&currObj` is pointing to the address of the `currObj` pointer, NOT to the `ObjectHoldingData` instance. If you want to see the address of the `ObjectHoldingData` instance, just print the pointer:

```
// No ampersand '&'.
cout << "Object " << currObj->item << " with memory reference " << currObj << "\n";
```

Comment: Oh right, forgot I do not need the &. Thanks for catching that!